# Why is the orthogonal complement of col(A) = ker(A*)?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, transpose

col(A) = column space of matrix A

ker(A<sup>*</sup>) = kernel (nullspace) of matrix A<sup>*</sup>

*(where A<sup>*</sup> is the conjugate transpose which is just A<sup>T</sup> for real matrices.)*

Why does orthogonal complement col(A) = ker(A<sup>*</sup>) ?

I am an engineer, not a mathematician. I'd appreciate an intuitive explanation. Thanks

Comment: You forgot to put an orthogonal complement there.  $\ker(A^*)=(\operatorname{image}(A))^\perp$, which is immediate when you think about $0=u\cdot Av=(A^*u)\cdot v$.

Comment: Thank you. I had it originally and second-guessed myself. Doh! I've corrected it now.